# Linux: Update DNS with client IP address after connecting via VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, fortigate

In [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/590802/dynamic-dns-registration-over-vpn/590834), the asker has a problem where clients connecting in over the VPN are not updating the DNS records with their SSLVPN Adapter IP address.

The solution is Windows turns out to be very simple - simply tick `Register this connection's addresses in DNS` in the SSLVPN adapter's  TCP/IP properties.

I am looking to achieve the same thing, but on Linux.

**Specifics:**

- The DNS is managed by Microsoft Active Directory.
- The client is running Ubuntu 18.04.
- The client is connecting to a Fortigate VPN using the `forticlientsslvpn_cli` command line client wrapped in a bash script.

Comment: How was this machine joined to the Windows domain?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is not part of the AD windows domain and the DNS is configured for secure updates